# Tried writing a do-while loop statement that prints out my statement, but it's not currently printing it

Tags: javascript, html, loops, do-while

So, I am trying to write a do-while loop statement that prints out the statement of my loop, but my browser isn't printing my text. How can I edit my code to do so?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>9. Looping Statements in Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>9. Looping Statements in Javascript</h1>
    <div id="playlist"></div>
    <div id="someResult"></div>
    <script>
        var playlist = [];
        playlist[0] = "Willy Wesly";
        playlist[1] = "Childish Gambino";
        playlist[2] = "Chance The Rapper";
        playlist[3] = "Travi$ Scott";
        playlist[4] = "Yeezy";

// while
    /*
    var i = 0;
    while (i < playlist.length) {
        var element = document.createElement('div');
        element.innerHTML = "Now Playing:  " + playlist[i];
         i++;
        document.body.appendChild(element);
}
*/

// do - while
var someResult = false;
do {
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerHTML = 'Will print AT LEAST once!';
}
while(someResult);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the element to the document body.

```
var someResult = false;
do {
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerHTML = 'Will print AT LEAST once!';

    //You need to add it to the body for it to show on the page
    document.body.appendChild( element );
}
while(someResult);
```

JSFiddle showing this: http://jsfiddle.net/azgxh59q/